# How to attach click event on dynamically appended inner elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series div elements appended to a parent div.
Attaching click event binds on parent element.

```js
var element = "";
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  element = element + "<div class='aClass'>"+j+"</div>";
}

$(".wrapper").append(function() {
  return $(element).click(foo);
});

function foo() {
  alert("index of element is:");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

I need to know which appended div is clicked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method

```js
var element = "";
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  element = element + "<div class='aClass'>j</div>";
}

$(".wrapper").append(function() {
  return $(element).click(foo);
});

function foo() {
  alert("index of element is:"+$(this).index());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a reference to the element which raised the event use the `this` keyword in the event handler. To retrieve its index, you can use jQuery's `index()` method.

Also note that your logic can be made more succinct by appending all the HTML in one operation and using a single delegated event handler. Try this:

```js
var elements = (new Array(10)).fill('<div class="aClass">j</div>');

$(".wrapper").append(elements).on('click', '.aClass', function() {
  console.log(`index of element is: ${$(this).index()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: I actually haven't seen anyone use that fill method. I've never seen it before actually and I write jQuery everyday for work. I'll definitely be looking into that as it seems pretty efficient. Using event delegation is the definitely the way to go here instead of creating new events for each new div

Answer (score 3):

You can append and attach an event on every iteration instead of at the end.

```js
for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  const element = $("<div class='aClass'>j</div>");
  element.click(() => foo(j));
  $(".wrapper").append(element);
}

function foo(index) {
  alert("index of element is: "+index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jquery and you want to append a bunch of `<div>`s to a wrapper and have a click event on each, instead of creating a brand new event for each of those `<div>`s I would use event delegation and attach the event to the parent `$('.wrapper')`, then catch the event in the children. It would be something like this.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    $('.wrapper').append($(`<div class="aClass">${ j }</div>`));
}

$('.wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
    const target = $(e.target);

    if (target.hasClass('aClass')) {
        console.log(target.index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an *anonymous* function to pass *`this`* object to the function so that you can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the position:

```js
var element = "";
for( var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
  element = element + "<div class='aClass'>"+j+"</div>";
}

$(".wrapper").append(function() {
  return $(element).click(function() {foo(this)});
});

function foo(el){
  console.log("index of element is:", $(el).text() + ' at index ' + $(el).index());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question is not to change the text of the element and then access it later. What will happen if OP don't want the text to be `0,1,2...` and in the question the text is `j` for all.

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo() {
  alert("index of element is:" +  $(this).text() + "-" + $(this).index());
}
```

```js
var element = "";
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  element = element + "<div class='aClass'>j</div>";
}

$(".wrapper").append(function() {
  return $(element).click(foo);
});

function foo() {
  alert("index of element is:" +  $(this).text() + "-" + $(this).index());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can `append()` inside the loop. And wrap `foo` inside wrapper and pass it to click.

```js
var element = "";
const wrapper = $(".wrapper");
for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
   element = "<div class='aClass'>j</div>";
   wrapper.append(function() {
     return $(element).click(() => foo(j));
   });
}
function foo(index){
  alert("index of element is:" + index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```